# 'QModelIndex' object has no attribute 'isvalid' Attribute Error

Tags: pyqt4

while working with QTreeView() i got this error in rowCount() method. Apparently syntax seems ok. Help please. Related Code lines are

```
def rowCount(self, parent):
        if not parent.isvalid():
            parentNode = self._rootNode
        else:
            parentNode = parent.internalPointer()
        return parentNode.childCount()
```

Comment: Please take a few seconds to check the [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/classes.html) before wasting your time posting questions like this on SO. The function is spelled [isValid](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html#isValid).

Comment: before posting this i tried isValid but it didn't work. after your suggestion i tried again and it didn't get fixed

Comment: What does "didn't work" and "didn't get fixed" mean?